# Do i need to meet all city states to found World Congress?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

In Brave New World, to found World Congress, do i need to be the first to discover Printing Press and:

- A. all other players?
- B. all other players and city states?

Answer (score 11):

You have to meet all the other players (human/computer), city states do not count.

Answer (score 1):

You have to meet only states, either players or AI. City states don't have any political abilities, so you don't have to meet them.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/World_Congress_(Civ5)
You can also found the World congress by advancing to the Industrial era instead.